# WebStorm | IntelliJ file hint toolbar | ribbon

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

How to change the color of this bar?

[image: WebStorm]

Comment: **I think** it would be `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Editor | Notification background`. If not that one -- also check `Color Scheme | General | Popups and Hints`. Unless it's provided by the actual GUI Theme (which is then not customisable in the UI)

Comment: that's correct: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Editor | Notification background` 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the **Notification background** style under `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Editor`. If not that one, then also check the most appropriate styles under `General | Popups and Hints`.

if it's not the one, then it could be provided by the actual GUI Theme (which is then not customisable in the UI).

[image]